# Filter Json data in AngularJs

Tags: android, json, wordpress

I want to show a picture in my app but the json data from the server looks like this

```
"property_plans":["~~~http:\/\/irandng.com\/melk\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/07\/plan4.jpg~~~http:\/\/irandng.com\/melk\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/07\/plan3.jpg~~~http:\/\/irandng.com\/melk\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/07\/plan1.jpg~~~http:\/\/irandng.com\/melk\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/07\/plan2.png"]
```

How can I show the pictures?  I have a problem with ~~~. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have a look at `string.split()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: i can not show this in my app can you get me my code to0 plas in html and angolar

Comment: You'll have to show some more of your code and a bit more effort. People are here to help, not write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string using the aptly named function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split